# Adding syntax highlighting for latex plugin in vim

Tags: vim, latex, syntax-highlighting

I am using a package called `outlines` for LaTeX. It adds commands such as `\1` `\2` `\3` etc.

They are not highlighted by default in vim. So, I created a file called `tex.vim` in my .vimrc/syntax folder, and put this in the file:

```
:syn match outline /\\[1-9]/
hi link outline Label
```

This works **only at the top level, not within a block**. In other words, it works before my `\begin{document}`, but not between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

This is pretty much useless. How can I get vim to recognize the syntax, regardless of where it appears in the document?

Comment: Did you consider using latex-suite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find the syntax group or cluster defined by the Tex syntax, and use `contained containedin=...`, but in your case, there is already a syntax group for statements, it's just that it doesn't include numbers. Therefore, you can just piggyback on the existing group and only add matching for numbers:

```
:syn match texStatement /\\\d/
```